# VBA attempting to open file which name contains characters above high-ascii (256)

Tags: vba, excel-2016

What I'd like to achieve is opening a file from the previously-stored variable. The problem is the filename sometimes contains characters like **ŰŐ**. VBA environment changes them to the closest one **UO**. So I'm unable to open a workbook included with "special" characters. What I have tried so far:

```
Sub open_last_modified()
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim files, folder, lmfile As String
Dim lmdate As Date
' a file previously created on desktop ( like őőőűűű.xlsx)
' with a proper filename, both method works very well
folder = ("C:\Users\szidzse\Desktop\")
files = Dir(folder & "*.*", vbNormal)

Do While files <> ""
On Error Resume Next 'if it contains non
  If FileDateTime(folder & files) > lmdate Then
       lmdate = FileDateTime(folder & files)
       lmfile = files 'the last modified file what i'd like to open even if it has non-ascii characters.
  End If
files = Dir
Loop

Set a = Workbooks.Open(folder & lmfile, ReadOnly:=True) 'does nothing when filename is not proper.
fso.CopyFile Source:=folder & lmfile,    Destination:=folder & "temp.xlsx" 'file not found (I've tried to copy and rename it to a proper name.)
End Sub
```

I've also tried `StrConv(string, vbFromUnicode or vbUnicode)` without success.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does `Dir` return a file name, even if using the invoked non ASCII characters? I cannot test that. I (only) suppose it does. Is my supposition correct?

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next function. It should replace the non ASCII characters with similar ones:

```
Function replaceNonASCIICh(x As String) As String
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To Len(x)
    If AscW(Mid(x, i, 1)) <> Asc(Mid(x, i, 1)) Then
        x = Replace(x, Mid(x, i, 1), Chr(Asc(Mid(x, i, 1))))
    End If
  Next i
  replaceNonASCIICh = x
End Function
```

I tested it on the two not ASCII characters we could see/copy, in the next way:

```
Sub testReplaceNonASCII()
  Dim x As String, result As String
  x = ChrW(368) & ChrW(79) 'the string containing the characters you show us
  result = replaceNonASCIICh(x)
  ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value = result 'in Immediate Window non ASCII characters cannot be seen as they are...
End Sub
```

I do not know what other characters should be involved. Please, test it on your cases and send some feedback.

Now, supposing that `Dir` returns all files from the folder, even if their name contain non ASCII characters, you should firstly iterate between all of them and change their names, using the above function (and Name function). If it looks complicated, but if `Dir` returns them, I will show you how to proceed...

If you share such a file (supposing it is not confidential) I can try testing the code I posted, only supposing that it should work...

**Edited**:

I copied the workbook you sent in a folder named "InvalidCharacters", like subfolder of the one running the code. Then, I (manually) changed its name adding a suffix and copy it again (keeping the non ASCII characters). Please, do the same and test the following code:

```
Sub changeNonASCIIFileName()
   Dim FSOLibrary As Object, fldObj As Object, fsoFile As Object
   Dim foldPath As String, fileName As String, newName As String
   Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    foldPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\InvalidCharacters\"
    Set fldObj = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(foldPath)
    For Each fsoFile In fldObj.files
        On Error Resume Next 'if no characters to be replaced you cannot rename the file...
         fsoFile.Name = replaceNonASCIICh(fsoFile.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

It uses the above function. Please, take care to be there!

I would like to receive some feedback after testing it...

Comment: unfortunately replacing doesn't solve this problem here's an xlxs file , so I want to open that from Excel via VBA[link]https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/i1qkq3jbkoy28d57n7x8k/Sample_invalid_ch-ract-rs_in_filename.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=geyvn1u09lpwfvw5cc9i8cioc

Comment: @Attila Ragó **What does "doesn't solve this problem" means**? If `Dir` does not return them, there are some other methods to iterate between all files in a folder. Did you succed changing the names, replacing the non ASCII characters and the workbooks still cannot be open? If you really need help, bring some more details... What about sharing of such a workbook, as I suggested? Even a dummy one. I do not care about its content...

Comment: @Attila Ragó Did you run it **as it is**, or had a small contribution to its adaptation? If as it is, didn't it return what you need (**in the active cell**)?

Comment: It seems like a found out the trick. When macro gets the last modified filename (now no matter what character it has). I also store string in a cell. Then at workbook.open method i simply declare cell.value as variable and it works. i don't know why it doesn't work inside the editor...

Comment: @Attila Ragó You should carefully read the last code comment (**'in Immediate Window non ASCII characters cannot be seen as they are...**)... Now, even if it works in the code example, it is not so simple to include it in your code, as it is. VBA will not found the file to change its name in that way. Now I am working with the (multiplied) sample you shared and I will post a piece of code able to do what you need. Of course, if you will solve it by yourself, it will be even better. You better learn things you discovered by yourself...

Comment: @Attila Ragó Please, test the code I posted after **editing** the initial answer and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru sorry for my late response.
Your code works, for me, it returns **uo** instead of **űő**. But gives `File not found.` when attempting to open. In my special case for opening a file, putting a question mark where the invalid character is doing the trick.
`Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\invalid??.xlsx")` opens successfully the file named: `invalidűő.xlsx`
Getting that file's last modified date is a bit trickier,if I tried to store as string it runs into error, file not found, so it must be done via FSO and a lot of mess with the strings, and telling the editor that *"Hey this is from Middle European code table!!"* so in my case:

`Chr(254)` is **ő** in the mid-euro table. If your string contains this char in the editor it handles as the following.
`Chr(254)` is **õ** in the western table.

Setting the string with the specified Unicode hex code here `ChrW$(&H151)` is the key. (Accented o letter). While `Chr(254)` is (o letter with tilde, or without).

```
Sub lmfile_check2()
Dim files As String
Dim folder As String
Dim lmdate As Date
Dim lmfile As String
files = Empty
For i = 1 To 11
folder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
files = Dir(folder & "*.*", vbNormal)

Do While files <> ""
On Error Resume Next

If FileDateTime(folder & files) = Empty Then GoTo 2
On Error GoTo 2
lmdate_2:


If FileDateTime(folder & files) > lmdate Or lmdate2 > lmdate Then
If IsEmpty(FileDateTime(folder & files)) Then
GoTo ende
End If
   lmfile = files '
   If lmdate2 > lmdate And lmdate <> Empty Then
   lmdate = lmdate2
   Else
   lmdate = FileDateTime(folder & files)
   End If
End If
GoTo ende
2:
If InStr(1, files, "hétfo") > 0 Then 'this section is for known invalid character
                Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                files2 = Replace(files, "hetfo", "hetf" & ChrW$(&H151), 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
                l = Len(files2)
                files2 = Left(files2, l - 5)
                Set f = fs.GetFile(folder & files2 & ChrW$(&H151) & ".xls")
                lmdate2 = f.DateLastModified
                If lmdate2 > lmdate Then
                lmdate = lmdate2 
                lmfile = Replace(files, "hetfo", "hetf" & "?", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
                GoTo vege
                End If
End If
GoTo lmdate_2
ende:
files = Dir
Loop


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = folder & lmfile
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4) = lmdate

Set f = Nothing

lmdate = Empty
lmfile = Empty
Next i

For i = 1 To 11
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1), "hétfo", "hétf" & "?", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
Next i
MsgBox "Vertig"

End Sub
```